# How to change PC connection settings programmatically?

Tags: android, android-settings

I am not able to find a method to *programmatically* change the PC settings such as selecting USB connecting method for **charge/MTP/Tethering** and other such options on an Android smartphone.

Is there any method to access and change such settings?

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) those options are part of Android's secure settings.
You need root permissions to change those settings from inside an app.

I suggest you have a read through [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/lTxvDrD6m-0).

Comment: I have root, so what is the answer?